# Grouping MySQL output using data in one of the columns

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

Query result:

```
+--------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| rol_id | pos_name  | role_name    | sys_name  |
+--------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|      2 | A Manager | Role A       | System A  |
|      1 | A Manager | Role B       | System A  |
|    105 | A Manager | Role A       | System B  |
|    106 | A Manager | Role B       | System B  |
|    107 | A Manager | Role C       | System B  |
|    108 | A Manager | Role D       | System B  |
|      4 | A Manager | Role A       | System C  |
|     25 | A Manager | Role A       | System C  |
|    100 | A Manager | Role A       | System C  |
```

Required output:

Position Name "A Manager" can access

- "System A"

  - "Role A"
  - "Role B"
- "System B"

  - "Role A"
  - "Role B"
  - "Role C"
  - "Role D"

etc.

Current code, using a `for` loop to grab the system names:

```
$posname = mysqli_fetch_array($posresult);
echo $posname['pos_name']. '<br/>';
echo 'A total of ' .$result->num_rows. ' rows were returned<br/>';
$numResults = $result->num_rows;

$all_results = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Append all rows to an array
    $all_results[] = $row;
}

for($i = 0; $i < $numResults; $i++){
    echo $all_results[$i]["sys_name"];
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

I was intending to learn nested loops next, to put the roles under each system.

But the above lists each system for every row in the array (expected behaviour with the current code), how could I group the output so it looks as above, with each system listed once and each role associated with it printed beneath it?

EDIT
Thought I was making progress but now getting all roles under each system: -

```
$posname = mysqli_fetch_array($posresult);
echo $posname['pos_name']. '<br/>';
echo 'A total of ' .$result->num_rows. ' rows were returned<br/><br/>';
$numResults = $result->num_rows;

$all_results = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
// Append all rows to an array
$all_results[] = $row;
}

$j = 0;
while ($j < $numResults) {
$sysName = $all_results[$j]["sys_name"];
echo $sysName;
echo '<br/>';

for($i = 0; $i < $numResults; $i++){
if ($all_results[$i]["sys_name"] = $all_results[$j]["sys_name"]){
echo $all_results[$i]["role_name"];
echo '<br/>';
}
}
echo '<br/><hr/>';
$j++;
```

EDIT: var output. System is the same in each row, which is strange because it isn't if you run the query in MySQL?

```
array 
(0 =>array
('rol_id' => '2','pos_name' => 'Manager A','role_name' => 'Role A','sys_name' => 'System A',),
1 =>array 
('rol_id' => '1','pos_name' => 'Manager A','role_name' => 'Role B','sys_name' => 'System A',),
2 =>array
('rol_id' => '105','pos_name' => 'Manager A','role_name' => 'Role A','sys_name' => 'System A',),
3 =>array 
('rol_id' => '106','pos_name' => 'Manager A','role_name' => 'Role B','sys_name' => 'System A',),
4 =>array 
('rol_id' => '107','pos_name' => 'Manager A','role_name' => 'Role C','sys_name' => 'System A',),
```

EDIT 2: IF I grab var_export after setting the array, the systems are correct. The above is if I var_export after the loops at the bottom of the code

EDIT 3: So I was using = instead of == in my IF statement! I'm not quite there, but the output is looking a lot better. Will update when I work the last part out. Thanks for the comment below

EDIT FINAL: The below gives what I want, I now see what @ADyson was saying below about comparing the last row with the current. I've used $control for this. Had to play around with where to increment it, but it works now. Thanks all

```
$all_results = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
// Append all rows to an array
$all_results[] = $row;
}
//var_export($all_results);

$j = 0;
$control = $j;
//$all_results[$row['sys_name']][] = $row;
while ($j < $numResults) {
if ($control == $j){
echo 'System Name: ' . $all_results[$j]["sys_name"];
echo '<br/>';

for($i = 0; $i < $numResults; $i++){
if ($all_results[$i]["sys_name"] == $all_results[$j]["sys_name"]){
echo 'Role: ' . $all_results[$i]["role_name"];
echo '<br/>';
$control++;
}
}
echo '<br/>';
}
$j++;
}
```

Comment: the secret to this is, during your loop you must keep a record of what the system name was in the previous row. If the system name in the current row is different to what it is in the current row, then you need to write a new header for the system name. If not, then don't.

Comment: if you're still stuck after giving that a try, provide me with the output of `var_export($all_results);` (so I can use it directly for testing) and I'll write you a little demo.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson I was just echoing out $i and $j to the screen. Even though both increment for each element in the array, and the Role Names cycle through, the System Name is always System A, even though $j is being incremented. I will edit the post now with the var output

Comment: Seen your edits. If you do figure it out finally, please post it as an answer below (don't update your _question_ with the _answer_ :-)). If you still need a bit more help then by all means please edit the question further and tag me in a comment.

Comment: @ADyson I have just added the solution to my question sorry! Then read your comment. Will paste in the Answer now. Thanks, you solved this with your first comment

Answer (score 1):

```
$all_results = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
// Append all rows to an array
$all_results[] = $row;
}
//var_export($all_results);

$j = 0;
$control = $j;
//$all_results[$row['sys_name']][] = $row;
while ($j < $numResults) {
if ($control == $j){
echo 'System Name: ' . $all_results[$j]["sys_name"];
echo '<br/>';

for($i = 0; $i < $numResults; $i++){
if ($all_results[$i]["sys_name"] == $all_results[$j]["sys_name"]){
echo 'Role: ' . $all_results[$i]["role_name"];
echo '<br/>';
$control++;
}
}
echo '<br/>';
}
$j++;
}
```

Thanks to @ADyson, see first comment for the great guidance. The $control is how I implemented the suggestion